# extracting multiple tags from xml using PHP

Tags: php, xml

Here is my address.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--Sample XML document -->
<AddressBook>
    <Addressentry>
        <firstName>jack</firstName>
        <lastName>S</lastName>
        <Address>2899,Ray Road</Address>
        <Email>jkjsvsdka@ghu.edu</Email>
    </Addressentry>
    <Addressentry>
        <firstName>Sid</firstName>
        <lastName>K</lastName>
        <Address>238,Baseline Road,TX</Address>
        <Email>sk@ghu.edu</Email>
        <Email>sk@gmail.com</Email>
    </Addressentry>
    <Addressentry>
        <firstName>Satya</firstName>
        <lastName>Yar</lastName>
        <Address>6,Rural Road,Tempe,AZ</Address>
        <Email>syarlag@ghu.edu</Email>
       <Email>ssya@gmail.com</Email>
        <Email>satag@yahoo.com</Email>
    </Addressentry>

</AddressBook>
```

I am trying to load all the entries using PHP code as below. Each addressentry can have one or more  tags. Right now from the code below I am able to extract only one  tag. My question is how do I extract all  tags associated with particular Addressentry. that is I want to print all emails on the same line.

```
<?php
$theData = simplexml_load_File("address.xml");

foreach($theData->Addressentry as $theAddress) {
    $theFirstName = $theAddress->firstName;
    $theLastName = $theAddress->lastName;
    $theAdd = $theAddress->Address;


    echo "<p>".$theFirstName."
    ".$theLastName."<br/>
    ".$theAdd."<br/>
    ".$theAddress->Email."<br/>
    </p>";


    unset($theFirstName);
    unset($theLastName);
    unset($theAdd);
    unset($theEmail);
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$emails = array();
foreach ($theAddress->Email as $email) {
    $emails[] = $email;
}
echo "<p>".$theFirstName."
    ".$theLastName."<br/>
    ".$theAdd."<br/>
    ".implode(', ', $emails)."<br/>
    </p>";
```